# Applying custom offsets and sizes of foundation grid

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

hey guys i am trying to create a layout which has like 8 columns on left and like 3.5 columns on right.
Now the problem is that 3.5 columns is not supported in in foundation. 
how can i achieve that?
Or can i do a custom margin and padding.If so, i guess the layout for mobile will break too.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change pretty much all properties of the grid in SASS version. If you make total column count 24(instead of 12) then 3.5 will be integer number 7. BUT! Much easier option will be nesting grid inside the grid(gridception) so you can subdivide section of arbitrary width (standard 1 to 12 columns) in up to 12 parts.

Comment: yeah but what to do if i only want to have the grid settings for a perticular page?like margins and paddings?thanks.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer then you need 2 grids because the parameters are part of the grid itself, they are hard coded inside.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a web-page with 11.5 columns.
One way is to customize foundation with 23 column grid structure and have 16 columns on left and 7 on right.Here is the link to customize foundation - [LINK](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation)

remove the components you dont need and have that stylesheet included for that specific page.